# SQL query help, ms sql server 2005 (group by and having)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I writing a query within ms sql server 2005 and having some trouble getting it to run. I need my query to include:

1. Include all docs from Date Range 2009-07-20 to 2009-08-04
2. Include a Sum column using the 'Size' field
3. Include a record count column
4. Group By Name

```
select Name, count(*) AS FileCount, SUM(Size)  
From alldocs 
Group by DirName 
HAVING TimeCreated >= '2009-07-20' AND 
TimeCreated <= '2009-08-04'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're querying on fields that are not aggregates (SUM, COUNT, AVG), you can use a normal WHERE:

```
SELECT
  DirName, count(*) AS FileCount, SUM(Size)
FROM
  alldocs 
WHERE
  TimeCreated >= '2009-07-20' 
  AND TimeCreated <= '2009-08-04'
GROUP BY
  DirName
```

You only need the HAVING if you want to limit something based on an aggreate, e.g.

```
HAVING Count(*) > 5
```

Marc

PS: If you want to display MB instead of bytes, use this query:

```
SELECT
  DirName, count(*) AS FileCount, SUM(Size) / (1024*1024) as 'Size MB'
FROM
  alldocs 
WHERE
  TimeCreated >= '2009-07-20' AND TimeCreated <= '2009-08-04'
GROUP BY
  DirName
```

Comment: is there an easy way run a conversion on the size field so that is displays MB verses Bytes?

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
select Name, count(*) AS FileCount, SUM(Size)
From alldocs
WHERE TimeCreated between '2009-07-20' AND '2009-08-04'
Group by DirName
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the *Name* column to the *Group By* list.

```
SELECT Name, count(*) AS FileCount, SUM(Size)
FROM alldocs
WHERE TimeCreated between '2009-07-20' AND '2009-08-04'
GROUP BY Name
```